# Ha proxy maintenance page

Tags: http, ubuntu, redirect, haproxy

I have got a `HAproxy` and I created maintenance page and I change it in configuration:

> Errorfile 503 /etc/haproxy/errors/maintenance.html

but Why can I force transition for all users when I will want to make service rest? How can I turn on and turn off this mode? Is it possible this way?